# Why does my Flutter app requests Run on Startup permission on Android?

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-permissions

In Playstore I can see my app is requestin that permission:

[image]

But im not requesting or using the permission, here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="XXX">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application ...
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you don't have vibration permission also, but it is present on the list... so it is introduced by some other part of software, mostly probably 3rd party lib. maybe one of your libs is requesting these "new" permissions? this "pack" of perms looks a bit like some background notification service, would start investigation in such implementation/lib if present

Comment: Thats a good point! But I am using many third party libs, but nothing has to do with background processing. Do you know a quick way to find out which dependency is requesting which permission?

Comment: sadly no... but background processing is good approach for many even trivial reasons, e.g. storing/saving some data or simple networking (its even mandatory in this case to run in different `Thread` than UI-one)